# The image resizing methods (resizeBilinear and resizeNearestNeighbor) in Tensorflow.js do not return the correct results

Tags: javascript, tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter

**Problem**

1. What is the difference between resizeBilinear(*1) and resizeNearestNeighbor(*2)?
   In particular, resizeNearestNeighbor does not return the correct image (half the image is black). (Half of the image is black.)
2. ResizeBilinear does not return the correct results for segmentation. (Half of the image is gray.)
   Why is that?
   This is very similar to the results of resizeNearestNeighbor.

**Background**

I want to develop an application that does segmentation in Tensorflow.js.
Fortunately, I have found some sample code for segmentation in Python. (*3)
I believe I can do segmentation in Tensorflow.js by converting the Keras model acquired there to the TFJS model.
I have tried to resize the images in Tensorflow.js but I can't get the right results.
Does anyone have any good ideas?

**Code**

Here's the source code I wrote. (I'm not used to writing JavaScript.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs"></script>
<canvas id="canvas1" width="256" height="256" style="border: 2px solid;"></canvas>
<canvas id='canvas2' width="128" height="128" style="border: 2px solid;"></canvas>
<canvas id='canvas3' width="128" height="128" style="border: 2px solid;"></canvas>
<canvas id='canvas4' width="128" height="128" style="border: 2px solid;"></canvas>
<canvas id='canvas5' width="128" height="128" style="border: 2px solid;"></canvas>
<script>

var inputImg = new Image();inputImg.src = "../00_resources/woman172.jpg";
const canvas1 = document.getElementById('canvas1');
const canvas2 = document.getElementById('canvas2');
const canvas3 = document.getElementById('canvas3');
const canvas4 = document.getElementById('canvas4');
const canvas5 = document.getElementById('canvas5');

const SIZE = 128;
const COL_CHANNEL = 3;
const BIN_CHANNEL = 1;

inputImg.onload = () => {
  const inCtx = canvas1.getContext('2d');
  inCtx.drawImage(inputImg, 0, 0, canvas1.width, canvas1.height);
};


(async() => {

    // load model
    let model = await tf.loadGraphModel('/tfjsdoc/Portrait-Segmentation/model/deconv_bnoptimized_munet_to_tfjs_graph_model/model.json');

    // image1 (original image)
    let img1 = tf.browser.fromPixels(canvas1, COL_CHANNEL);
    tf.browser.toPixels(img1, canvas2);// OK

    // image2 (resized image - using 'resizeNearestNeighbor')
    let img2 = img1.resizeNearestNeighbor([SIZE, SIZE]).toFloat().div(tf.scalar(255));
    tf.browser.toPixels(img2, canvas3);// NG

    // image3 (resized image - using 'resizeBilinear')
    let img3 = img1.resizeBilinear([SIZE, SIZE]).toFloat().div(tf.scalar(255));
    tf.browser.toPixels(img3, canvas4);// OK?

    // predict (image3 is used to make predictions, but the same problem occurs as in image2)
    let pred = await model.predict(tf.reshape(img3, [-1,SIZE,SIZE,COL_CHANNEL])).data();
    tf.browser.toPixels(tf.tensor(pred, [SIZE,SIZE, BIN_CHANNEL]), canvas5);// NG

})();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Capturing the Execution Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZ2KW.png)

From left to right.

- original image
- The original image is taken and drawn on canvas
- Original image resized using resizeNearestNeighbor and drawn on canvas (half of the image is black)
- Original image resized using resizeBilinear and drawn on canvas (looks right)
- Segmentation of the original image resized using resizeBilinear and drawn on canvas (half of the image is gray)

**References**

(*1) https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#image.resizeBilinear

(*2) https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#image.resizeNearestNeighbor

(*3) https://github.com/anilsathyan7/Portrait-Segmentation

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, it seems like both accomplish similar resizing of the input image. ResizeBilinear performs a bilinear interpolation on the image.

Comment: Dear ytrao,

Thank you for your reply.

You are correct in your assertion.
I have achieved the size change.
As I noted in my initial post, please check out the image below.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZ2KW.png

The problem I'm having is that the image is incomplete and the bottom half of the image is lost after resizing.
Do you know why this is the case?
I would also like to know how to avoid this.

Thank you and best regards,